# "Failed to Open database. Closing it" in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, search

I dont know why my own database has failed to open. I already included it inside the folder assets and followed the steps on this website

[using your own sqlite database in android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

I've been working on this for many days; unfortunately, I'm still newbie with android. Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong?

DatabaseHandler.java

```
package com.example.awesome;

/*
 * DatabaseHandler.java
 * Version 11
 * Add sorting list
 */
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
//import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.example.awesome/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "AcademicLocation";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    // All tables name
    private static final String TABLE_UKMLOCATION = "UKM_Location";

    // All Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String KEY_ALAMAT = "Alamat";  
    private static final String KEY_NOTEL = "No_tel";
    private static final String KEY_FAX = "Fax";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_TRANSPORT = "Transport";
    private static final String KEY_LANDMARK = "Landmark";
    private static final String KEY_WEBSITE = "Website";
    private static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "Category";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException { 
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist) {
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }
        else {
                    this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }
    }

       private boolean checkDataBase(){ 
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet. 
        }

        if(checkDB != null){ 
            checkDB.close(); 
        } 
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

       private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }  

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------
     * UKM_Location
     * --------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // Adding new Poi
    public void addUkmLocation(UkmLocation UKM_Location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, UKM_Location.getID()); // ID
        values.put(KEY_NAME, UKM_Location.getName()); //    Name
        values.put(KEY_ALAMAT, UKM_Location.getAlamat()); // Addr
        values.put(KEY_NOTEL, UKM_Location.getNotel()); // Phone
        values.put(KEY_FAX, UKM_Location.getFax()); //  Fax
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, UKM_Location.getEmail()); // Emel
        values.put(KEY_TRANSPORT, UKM_Location.getTransport()); // Transport
        values.put(KEY_LANDMARK, UKM_Location.getLandmark()); // Landmark
        values.put(KEY_WEBSITE, UKM_Location.getWebsite()); // Website
        values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, UKM_Location.getCategory()); // Category

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_UKMLOCATION, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single Poi
    public UkmLocation getUkmLocation(String _id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_UKMLOCATION, 
                new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ALAMAT,KEY_NOTEL, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_TRANSPORT, 
                KEY_LANDMARK,KEY_WEBSITE, KEY_CATEGORY }, 
                KEY_ID + "=?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf( _id) }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        UkmLocation poi = new UkmLocation(cursor.getString(0), 
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                cursor.getString(9));

        // return poi
        return poi;
    }

    // Getting single Poi by Category
    public UkmLocation getUkmLocationByCategory(String Category) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_UKMLOCATION, 
                new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ALAMAT,KEY_NOTEL, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_TRANSPORT, 
                KEY_LANDMARK,KEY_WEBSITE, KEY_CATEGORY }, 
                KEY_CATEGORY + "=?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf( Category) }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        UkmLocation poi = new UkmLocation(cursor.getString(0), 
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                cursor.getString(9));

        // return poi
        return poi;
    }

    // Getting single Poi by name
    public UkmLocation getUkmLocationByName(String Name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_UKMLOCATION, 
                new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ALAMAT,KEY_NOTEL, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_TRANSPORT, 
                KEY_LANDMARK,KEY_WEBSITE, KEY_CATEGORY },
                KEY_NAME + "=?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf(Name) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        UkmLocation poi = new UkmLocation(cursor.getString(0), 
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                cursor.getString(9));
        // return poi
        return poi;
    }   

    // Getting all Poi
    public List<UkmLocation> getAllPoi() {
        List<UkmLocation> locationList = new ArrayList<UkmLocation>();
        //Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_UKMLOCATION;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UkmLocation poi = new UkmLocation();
                poi.setID(cursor.getString(0));
                poi.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                poi.setAlamat(cursor.getString(2));
                poi.setNotel(cursor.getString(3));
                poi.setFax(cursor.getString(4));
                poi.setEmail(cursor.getString(5));
                poi.setTransport(cursor.getString(6));
                poi.setLandmark(cursor.getString(7));
                poi.setWebsite(cursor.getString(8));
                poi.setCategory(cursor.getString(9));
                //Adding poi to list
                locationList.add(poi);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        //sorting list
        Collections.sort(locationList,new Comparator<UkmLocation>() {
            public int compare(UkmLocation poi, UkmLocation otherPoi) {
                return poi.getName().compareTo(otherPoi.getName());
            }
        });

        // return Poi list
        db.close();
        return locationList;
    }

    //----
    // Getting all Kategori
        public List<UkmLocation> getCategoryFaculty() {
            List<UkmLocation> kategoriList = new ArrayList<UkmLocation>();
            //Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_UKMLOCATION + " WHERE " + 
                    KEY_CATEGORY + "= 'Faculty'"; 

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            //looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    UkmLocation kategori = new UkmLocation();
                    kategori.setID(cursor.getString(0));
                    kategori.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    kategori.setAlamat(cursor.getString(2));
                    kategori.setNotel(cursor.getString(3));
                    kategori.setFax(cursor.getString(4));
                    kategori.setEmail(cursor.getString(5));
                    kategori.setTransport(cursor.getString(6));
                    kategori.setLandmark(cursor.getString(7));
                    kategori.setWebsite(cursor.getString(8));
                    kategori.setCategory(cursor.getString(9));
                    //Adding kategori to list
                    kategoriList.add(kategori);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return Kategori list
            return kategoriList;
        }

    //----
    // Updating single Poi
    public int updatePoi(UkmLocation UKM_Location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, UKM_Location.getName()); // Poi Name
        values.put(KEY_ALAMAT, UKM_Location.getAlamat()); // Poi Addr
        values.put(KEY_NOTEL, UKM_Location.getNotel()); // Phone
        values.put(KEY_FAX, UKM_Location.getFax()); //  Fax
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, UKM_Location.getEmail()); // Emel
        values.put(KEY_TRANSPORT, UKM_Location.getTransport()); // Transport
        values.put(KEY_LANDMARK, UKM_Location.getLandmark()); // Landmark
        values.put(KEY_WEBSITE, UKM_Location.getWebsite()); // Website
        values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, UKM_Location.getCategory()); // Category

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_UKMLOCATION, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf(UKM_Location.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single Poi
    public void deletePoi(UkmLocation UKM_Location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_UKMLOCATION, KEY_ID + " =?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf(UKM_Location.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }   

    // Getting Poi Count
    public int getUkmLocationCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_UKMLOCATION;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    //  cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }   

    // Delete all Poi
    public void deleteAllPoi(){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_UKMLOCATION);
        db.close();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full database name (".db"):

```
private static String DB_NAME = "AcademicLocation.db";
```

Here are the other differences from what I have used that works:

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException { 
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(!dbExist) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                this.close();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
```

My checkDatabase():

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

I also just noticed this, `"data/data/com.example.awesome/databases/";`

I think it should be: `"/data/data/com.example.awesome/databases/";`

Comment: but my db inside the assets doesn't have .db , then do i need to rename the database inside the asset also?

Comment: what extension does it have?

Comment: at first it was .sqlite then, i change delete the ".sqlite" 
my db name inside asset just "AcademicLocation"

Comment: will it open as a database in a database explorer program on your computer?

Comment: that one, I'm not sure. never test it yet. i go through people's coding, they are mostly don't have any extension for their database. I thought it will be okay.

Comment: I load my database from the assets folder and that was one of the differences I saw was that I use the extension in my name. I will post the other differences and see if they work for you since mine works fine.